# Can't avoid the nullptr in C when I am doing a positive integer check

Tags: c, nullptr

I am working on functions and pointers, and have been spending more than 12 hours debugging my code cluelessly, searching over nullptr in here but no solution could fix this. Can someone please offer a helping hand?  Truly appreciated

This function is to input some numbers (the task gives us a default -1 0 and 24) for it to check if they are positive integers. I am to write this int getIntPositive(int *xPtr) functions and pass the value back to the preset function int testIntFunction(void). This test function and the rest of the codes in the main.c are not to be modified. To make it simple and just focus the point I fail to debug, I have deleted the rest of the codes from my main.c

The target is that I must pass Test 1 2 and 3, but right now either I can only pass Test 1 and receive nullptr on Test 2, or I can pass Test 2 but fail Test 1 and 3 (Reason: I have to make intA == intB but I donno why it became intA = 0 and int=20 which they cannot be equal. Screen cap posted below)

```
// ---------------------------------------
// Macros and headers
// ---------------------------------------
#define MAX_PROD 3
#define TEST_NEG    -1
#define TEST_ZERO   0
#define TEST_INT    24
#define TEST_DBL    82.5
#include <stdio.h>

// ---------------------------------------
// Function prototypes
// ---------------------------------------
int testIntFunction(void);
int getIntPositive(int *xPtr);

// ---------------------------------------
// Main entry-point to the program (main.c) Must not modify, fixed
// ---------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    int preTestFailed = 0;

    printf("============================\n");
    printf("Pre-testing Helper Functions\n");
    printf("============================\n\n");
    
    preTestFailed += testIntFunction();

    if (preTestFailed)
    {
        printf("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n");
        printf("  Pretesting revealed ERRORS in the helper functions.\n");
        printf("  Review where the tests failed and fix these errors\n");
        printf("  before continuing.\n");
        printf("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("===========================\n");
        printf("Starting Main Program Logic\n");
        printf("===========================\n\n");

        // Entry-point to program logic
        start();
    }

    return 0;
}
// ---------------------------------------
// My own function (placed in another .c file) The only part can be modified.
// ---------------------------------------

// 1. Get user input of int type and validate for a positive non-zero number
//    (return the number while also assigning it to the pointer argument)
int getIntPositive(int *xPtr)
{
    int x;
    int flag = 0;
    do {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Enter a positive value: ");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
            *xPtr = x;
            xPtr = &x;
        }
    } while (flag != 0);
    return *xPtr;
}
// ---------------------------------------
// Preset functions ( Must not modify, fixed)
// ---------------------------------------
int testIntFunction(void)
{
    int intA = 0, intB = 0, fail=0;

    printf("------------------------\n");
    printf("Function: getIntPositive\n");
    printf("------------------------\n");
    printf("For each of these tests, enter the following\n");
    printf("three values (space delimited):  %d %d %d\n\n", TEST_NEG, TEST_ZERO, TEST_INT);

    //-----------------------------------
    // Test-1: argument and return value
    printf("TEST-1: ");
    intB = getIntPositive(&intA);
    if (intA == intB && intA == TEST_INT)
    {
        printf("<PASSED>\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
        fail++;
    }

    //-----------------------------------
    // Test-2: return value only
    intA = intB = 0;
    printf("TEST-2: ");
    intA = getIntPositive(NULL);
    if (intA == TEST_INT)
    {
        printf("<PASSED>\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
        fail++;
    }

    //-----------------------------------
    // Test-3: argument only
    intA = intB = 0;
    printf("TEST-3: ");
    getIntPositive(&intA);
    if (intA == TEST_INT)
    {
        printf("<PASSED>\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
        fail++;
    }

    return fail;
}
void start() {}
```

Here is the output:

```
> ============================
> Pre-testing Helper Functions
> ============================
> 
> ------------------------
> Function: getIntPositive
> ------------------------
> For each of these tests, enter the following
> three values (space delimited):  -1 0 24
> 
> TEST-1: -1 0 24
> ERROR: Enter a positive value: ERROR: Enter a positive value: <PASSED>
> TEST-2: -1 0 24
> ERROR: Enter a positive value: ERROR: Enter a positive value:
```

It stopped for a nullptr error and I tried to look at local in the console, it says x = 24 and xPtr = 0x00000000{???}. Like this below:

[The capture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS1JW.jpg)

If I modify the order from this

```
else
{
  flag = 0;
  *xPtr = x;
  xPtr = &x;
}
```

to

```
else
{
  flag = 0;
  xPtr = &x;
  *xPtr = x;
}
```

then the nullptr error will be gone, but I won't be able to pass Test-1 and some logic error occurs like this:

```
============================
Pre-testing Helper Functions
============================

------------------------
Function: getIntPositive
------------------------
For each of these tests, enter the following
three values (space delimited):  -1 0 24

TEST-1: -1 0 24
ERROR: Enter a positive value: ERROR: Enter a positive value: <!!! FAILED !!!>
TEST-2: -1 0 24
ERROR: Enter a positive value: ERROR: Enter a positive value: <PASSED>
TEST-3: -1 0 24
ERROR: Enter a positive value: ERROR: Enter a positive value: <!!! FAILED !!!>
```

Screen captured the value became intA = 0 and intB = 24 which doesn't make sense to me.

[The capture of this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWQUV.jpg)

Comment: What should happen if user enters in text like `"abc\n"`, `"789def\n"`, `"\n"`, or `"123 456\n"`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the only input allowed is -1 0 24 which must follow their input. Still a beginner exercise so it is not to consider char and other numbers yet. If entered abc it will become a loop or errors until ctrl c

Comment: You are clumping "error" (EOF, negative) with "does not match format" (0) in a way that will hang on unexpected input. Perhaps `switch(scanf(" %d", &x)) { case EOF: /* bail */... case 0: /* remove line */... case 1: ... }`?

Comment: The term `nullptr` is exclusive to C++ (C++11 and beyond). There is nothing called "nullptr" in C.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `*xPtr = x;`, do `if (xPtr) *xPtr = x;`, and later do `return x;`.

The `if (xPtr) ...` does the `...` only if *xPtr* is not NULL.

Comment: Thank you sir it works like a charm! Is it because if xPtr becomes null, it will also reset *xPtr to 0 then it indirect reference the x to 0 as well? Sorry I am still a newbie here and can't upvote your answer yet, but surely will do it after I unlocked

Comment: @AlpacaMa You can also mark it as solved by clicking check if it solved your question. When `xPtr == NULL`, there is no `xPtr`; dereferencing a null pointer `*xPtr` is undefined behaviour, so you have to check in this case before you write there.

Comment: @AlpacaMa: You may want to read some introduction about pointers in C, e.g. https://www.studytonight.com/c/pointers-in-c.php and https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers . If it's still unclear how pointers work in your program, please ask a separate question on StackOverflow.